# Polymer firebase-auth on-success event fires twice

Tags: firebase, polymer

I am learning Polymer. So far I love it, but this has me stumped. I am using Firebase for the back end of an app I am developing.

I have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/firebase-element/firebase-auth.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="my-template">
      <firebase-auth id="firebase" 
        user="{{user}}" 
        status-known="{{statusKnown}}" 
        location="https://****.firebaseio.com"
        provider="password"
        on-error="onError"
        on-login="onSuccess"
        on-logout="onSuccess">
      </firebase-auth>
      <div>status: {{statusKnown}}</div>
      <div>user: {{user.uid}}</div>
      <button on-tap="login">login</button>
      <button on-tap="logout">logout</button>
    </template>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
        var template = document.getElementById('my-template');
        var fb = document.getElementById('firebase');
        template.login = function() {
          fb.login({email: 'email@example.com', password: 'password'});
        };
        template.logout = function() {
          console.log('logout', this);
          fb.logout();
        };
        template.onError = function(e) {
          console.log('onError', e);
        };
        template.onSuccess = function(e) {
          console.log('onSuccess', e);
        };
      });      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click "login", I see this in the console:

```
onSuccess Event {isTrusted: false, detail: Object}
onSuccess Event {isTrusted: false, detail: Object}
```

My question is, why does onSuccess fire twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue which is waiting answer: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/firebase-element/pull/67

You can work normally with Firebase apart from that.

If you are interested, please take a look also here, I am creating a set that will extend the basic functionalities of Firebase: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended

Comment: you're welcome! also, my set is a WIP, if you have any feedback, please do not hesitate! :)